# Java: Detecting if a variable is a String or an Integer

Tags: java, string

I'm look for some help on a bit of homework I have. I want the user to enter a numerical String, then convert it to an Integer. But I want to make a loop that will detect if the user entered in the wrong value such as "One Hundred" as apposed to "100".

What I was thinking was to do something like this:

```
    do{
        numStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a year in numarical form:"
                        + "\n(Ex. 1995):");
        num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
            if(num!=Integer){
            tryagainstr=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entered value is not acceptable."
                                  + "\nPress 1 to try again or Press 2 to exit.");
    tryagain=Integer.parseInt(tryagainstr);
            }
            else{
            *Rest of the code...*
            }
            }while (tryagain==1);
```

But I don't know how to define that "Integer" value. I essentially want it to see if it is a number or not to prevent it from crashing if the user enters the wrong thing.

Comment: [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method throws `NumberFormatException` if the input is not parseable as an integer. You just have to use a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
int num;
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number please");
while(true)
{
    if(s==null) 
        break; // if you press cancel it will exit
    try {
        num=Integer.parseInt(s);
        break;
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Not a number , Try Again");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand the try/catch better now. I ran something similar to this where I told it to do{ try/catch }while a variable equaled 1, and every time it went to the catch the variable stayed 1 to keep looping. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Try use `instanceof` , this method will help you with check between many types

> Example

```
if (s instanceof String ){
// s is String
}else if(s instanceof Integer){
// s is Integer value
}
```

If you want just check between integer and string you can use @NKukhar code

```
try{
        Integer.valueOf(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //not an integer
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
    try{
        Integer.valueOf(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //not an integer
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to validate the format of the string, and accept only numeric values on it:

```
Pattern.matches("/^\d+$/", numStr)
```

The `matches` method will return `true` if `numString` contains a valid numeric sequence, but of course the input can be way above an `Integer`'s capacity. In that case, you can consider switching to a `long` or a `BigInteger` type.