# How do I make a program that takes a string but disallows numbers?

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

I'm developing a game and it asks for a username at the start which will then be added to a txt file and saved. But the problem is that the user can write absolutely anything. Their usernames are infinite and can contain special characters and numbers which I do not want. And I have no idea how to stop it. I am writing in Java

The code I use to ask for a username is

```
player = new Player(level, 0, 0, input, JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Please enter a username"));
```

And in the constructor for player it is simply

```
public Player(Level level, x, y, InputHandler input, String username)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14967412/3908355

Comment: @gurinderhans that link is the opposite of what he wants.

Comment: @gurinderhans That shows how to make sure the string is an integer, I want to make sure it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep prompting the user to enter valid information until they do.

```
String username = null;
do {
    username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a username");
    // check if the username is invalid
    if(username.length() > 12 || username.length() < 4 || !username.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")) {
        // show the user why they cant enter that username
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username must be:\nbetween 4 and 12 characters characters\nonly letters and numbers", "Invalid Username", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        // do the loop again
        username = null; 
    }
} while(username == null);
// at this point in the execution we can say that the username String is a valid username
```

Comment: Thank you! Took me so long to wrap my head around this one :) I apologise for asking a question that has "already been answered" but I couldn't find that original post and ug_ has shown me how to do it properly anyway. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways you might be able to achieve this...

### You could...

Use a `JFormattedField`...

[image: Formatted Fields]

See [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more details

### You could...

Use a `DocumentFilter`, which would allow you to do real time filtering of the text been applied to a text field and reject if it didn't meet your requirements.

See [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details